# Extract method return type in method decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to add typing information to method decorator so I could properly type argument based on decorated method result.
Type of first parameter in my decorator need to be partial of return type of decorated method.
Based on `TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>` it should be possible.
However trying this doesn't give proper results - no suggestions (intelij IDE) for `props` arguments - so probably typing is wrong.

```
function Serialize<R, T extends (...args : any[]) => Promise<R>> (
    props : (keyof R)[], 
) : (target, method, descriptor : TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => void
{
    ...
}

class Bar
{
    public name : string;
}

class Foo 
{

    @Serialize([
        'name',
    ])
    public async exec() : Promise<Bar>
    {
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?